# Issues with Access 2003 project in using SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

Our company has a Access 2003 project that runs on a SQL Server 2000 database.  We installed SQL Server 2005 on a new box and migrated the database from SQL 2000 to SQL 2005.  The Access 2003 project is now pointing to the new database.  After the upgrade the Access 2003 project fails when trying to execute a stored procedure.  Upon investigation an error message is presented saying that the stored procedure does not exist.  When I view the available stored procedures the names appear but with a ;1 a the end.

1. Is this an issue of incompatibility between Access 2003 and SQL Server 2005 or could I have done something incorrectly during the migration?
2. I saw another post which mentioned upgrading to Access 2007.  Is this a possible solution?

Comment: Ignore the access component for a moment...when you upgraded from MSSQL 2000 to 2005, all of your stored procedures were renamed to include ;1 at the end of them?  Can't say i've ever seen that before.  Solution seems simple, rename the storedproc...but dunno as to why it would do that.

Answer (score 0):

The postfix number is an arcane feature of SQL Server going back years - it allows you to create multiple procedures with the same name (yeah, like that's not going to confuse anyone ever).

It's deprecated so it's hardly ever seen but whatever process your migration did seems to have caused it.

Comment: Been thinking about it, but I can't think of a reason why or mechanism how a migration might have done this

Comment: I know Rikalous, this doesn't make much sense as to why it'd do this.  The only explaination I can come up with here is the migration was done twice (first instance with regular names, second instance with the renamed procedures), then the first migration was 'rolledback'.  That explaination seems rather absurd though